# Get src of image file stored in dtabase?

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a dessert model in django with a property called picture:

```
class Dessert(models.Model): 
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
        description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True) 
        picture = models.ImageField(upload_to ='uploads/desserts-pics/', max_length=100) 
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)]) 
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="desserts")

 
        def __str__(self): 
                return self.name + " ($" + str(self.price) +")"
```

And i want to show the image in my front with react, like this:

```
       <img src={dessert.picture}>
```

dessert is an instance of the Dessert model witch i got from a request, but the picture is a file not an image, how the hell do i get the src? sorry, i know it's a silly question but i didn't find the answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a react user.  However, the HTML tag you show (if it's similar) would need some changes to display the image field of your model instance.  Let's assume you have a simple view that shows a dessert, like...

```
def show_dessert(request):

    d = Dessert.objects.get(id=1)
    context = {'d':d}
    return render(request, "pages/my_template.html", context)
```

With `d` as your desert object, you would show the image using `.url`, like:

```
<img src="{{d.picture.url}}">
```

Find more information on serving files and photos in [Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models).

This answer also assumes you have correctly configured your static files settings.  [More info about that here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/).